# how to delete multiple photos from the folder when deleting it from database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js

When I check multiple checkboxes for deleting multiple rows it delete the records with image url form database but it does not delete the images from public folder. if anyone can help me with.

**for deleting single record the below code worked perfectly it delete the record form database and also delete photo from folder too.**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        //

        // $this->authorize('isAdmin');
        $Employee = Employee::findOrFail($id);
         $currentPhoto = $Employee->photo;
         $currentdatePhoto = $Employee->afghanidatephoto;
        $EmployeePhoto = (public_path('img/emp/').$currentPhoto);
         $EmployeedatePhoto = (public_path('img/date/').$currentdatePhoto);
        if(file_exists($EmployeedatePhoto)){
            @unlink($EmployeedatePhoto);

        }
       if(file_exists($EmployeePhoto))
        {
             @unlink($EmployeePhoto);

        }
        $Employee->delete();
        return ['message'=>'Employee Deleted Successfully'];
    }
```

**function in my EmployeeController :**

```
public function multipledelete(Request $request)
            {
                try 
                    {  
                    Employee::whereIn('id', $request->id)->delete(); 

                        return response()->json('data deleted');
                    }

                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
                    }
             }
```

**Code in API:**

```
Route::delete('multipledelete','API\EmployeeController@multipledelete');
```

**Cod in Employee.vue for delete action is :**

```
delt() {
      var chekboxs = document.getElementById("chekboxs");
      if (chekboxs.checked) {
        swal
          .fire({
            title: "Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?",
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
          })
          .then(result => {
            //Send request to the server
            if (result.value) {
              axios
                .delete("api/multipledelete", {
                  params: { id: this.checkedRows }
                })
                .then(() => {
                  toast.fire({
                    type: "success",
                    title: "Your Selected Employees are successfully deleted!"
                  });
                  Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log(e);
                });
            }
          });
      } else {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "You didn't check anything to be deleted please check it!"
        });
      }
    }
```

**Checkbox is :**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        :value="employee.id"
                        v-model="checkedRows"
                        id="chekboxs"
                      />
                      <label class="form-check-label"></label>
                    </div>
```

**Button is :**

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom:-29px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="delt">
                      <i class="fas fa-user-minus"></i>
                      Delete Multiple
                      <!-- <grid-loader v-show="seen" :loading="loading" :color="color" :size="size"></grid-loader> -->
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

**I have tried this code but id does not worked.**

```
public function multipledelete(Request $request)
            {
                try 
                    {  
                    $Employee = Employee::whereIn('id', $request->id)->delete(); 
                    $currentPhoto = $Employee->photo;
         $currentdatePhoto = $Employee->afghanidatephoto;
        $EmployeePhoto = (public_path('img/emp/').$currentPhoto);
         $EmployeedatePhoto = (public_path('img/date/').$currentdatePhoto);
        if(file_exists($EmployeedatePhoto)){
            @unlink($EmployeedatePhoto);

        }
       if(file_exists($EmployeePhoto))
        {
             @unlink($EmployeePhoto);

        }
        $Employee->delete();
                        return response()->json('data deleted');
                    }

                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
                    }
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach with your current code in mind is to simply loop over the employees and delete as required:

```php
$employees = Employee::whereIn('id', $request->id)->get(); 
foreach($employees AS $employee){
    $currentPhoto = $employee->photo;
    $currentdatePhoto = $employee->afghanidatephoto;

    $employeePhoto = (public_path('img/emp/').$currentPhoto);
    $employeedatePhoto = (public_path('img/date/').$currentdatePhoto);

    if(file_exists($employeedatePhoto)){
        @unlink($employeedatePhoto);
    }

    if(file_exists($employeePhoto)){
        @unlink($employeePhoto);
    }

    $employee->delete();
}
```

You can wrap the `foreach()` in a `try { ... } catch { ... }` block.

The reason your code had issues starts with this line:

```
$Employee = Employee::whereIn('id', $request->id)->delete();
```

By finalizing that query with `->delete()`, you're deleting the records that match ids. Next, trying to perform operations on `$Employee` won't work, as `->delete()` doesn't return an `object` (I believe it returns a boolean, `true`), so `$Employee->{ ... }` is an error.

With all of that in mind, you should be able to query, loop and delete your Employees and their images.